# Formatting datestring using regional settings in VC++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, date, formatting

I need to format a datestring using the regional options from my Control Panel. I need to format the both short (MM DD) and long (YY MM DD). Is there any function in Visual C++ to get the format strings?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an article which describes how to get the format string from the locale on Windows and process it manually: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/date_time_format.aspx